# Mobile device's Contact list within the app's UI

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I use [**Contacts**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/) native plugin on `Ionic 3` app. It is working fine. But do you know how can I implement it within the app's UI? At this moment it is(`contact list`) loading outside the app. After I select the contact it comes back to the app's UI.Any clue? Is this not possible since it is a native feature of the phone?

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {  
     if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.contacts.pickContact().then(response => {
         });
      }
  }
```

***Like this:*** I have extracted this from [**Zoiper**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app&hl=en) app. Can we do this using `Ionic 3`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of contacts like this:

```
import { Contacts, ContactFieldType, ContactFindOptions } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

 constructor() {

    Contacts.find(['displayName', 'name', 'phoneNumbers', 'emails'], {filter: "", multiple: true})
    .then(data => {
      this.allContacts = data
    });
```

Then create a clickable list or what you want with **allContacts**

Comment: I don't think it is an easy task since that native contact component has a lot of features. i.e. search/sorting/alphabetic search and etc. Hope there is no method to include that component directly to app's UI no?